# Learning Hibernate and have such errors could not extract ResultSet и Table '...' doesn't exist?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Educational work - to create Entity on a DB.
And on the basis of a DB to collect one more column.
"Code a new LinkedPurchaseList table that populates based on the data in the PurchaseList table."

I've been sitting for a week, I can not understand what I'm doing wrong. I will be grateful if you help.
If it’s wrong, I designed something or there is not enough information, please tell me (my first post).
ERROR:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getDatabaseSnapshot(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1568)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:652)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:640)
    at Main.main(Main.java:44)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'skillbox.linkedpurchaselist' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 11 more
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skillbox</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Fuckdapolice31</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="Course"></mapping>
        <mapping class="Purchaselist"></mapping>
        <mapping class="LinkedPurchaseList"></mapping>
        <mapping class="Student"></mapping>
        <mapping class="Subscription"></mapping>
        <mapping class="Teacher"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(registry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction(); //открываем транзакцию

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder(); //строит объекты запросов

        CriteriaQuery<Purchaselist> query = builder.createQuery(Purchaselist.class); //возвращает запрос, указывает тип данных
        Root<Purchaselist> root = query.from(Purchaselist.class); //корневой объект, от которого производится обход дерева
        query.select(root);
        List<Purchaselist> purchaselist = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        for (Purchaselist p : purchaselist) {
            LinkedPurchaseList linkedPurchaseList = new LinkedPurchaseList();

            String courseName = p.getCourseName();
            String studentName = p.getStudentName();
            int studentId = p.getStudent().getId();
            int courseId = p.getCourse().getId();

            linkedPurchaseList.setId(new LPKey(studentName,courseName));
            linkedPurchaseList.setStudentId(studentId);
            linkedPurchaseList.setCourseId(courseId);
            linkedPurchaseList.setStudentName(studentName);
            linkedPurchaseList.setCourseName(courseName);
            linkedPurchaseList.setPrice(p.getPrice());
            linkedPurchaseList.setSubDate(p.getSubDate());
            session.saveOrUpdate(linkedPurchaseList);
        }

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Courses")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Course implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int duration;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "enum")
    private CourseType type;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Teacher teacher;

    @Column(name = "students_count")
    private Integer studentsCount;

    private Integer price;

    @Column(name = "price_per_hour")
    private float pricePerOur;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Subscriptions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    private List<Student> students;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private List<Purchaselist> pyrch;
}
```

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "purchaseList")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Purchaselist implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PKey id;
    @Column(name = "student_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String studentName;
    @Column(name = "course_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String courseName;
    private int price;
    @Column(name = "subscription_date", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date subDate;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_name",referencedColumnName = "name",insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="course_name",referencedColumnName = "name",insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private Course course;
}
```

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "LinkedPurchaseList")
@Getter
@Setter
public class LinkedPurchaseList implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private LPKey id;
    @Column(name = "sId", insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private int studentId;
    @Column(name = "cId", insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private int courseId;
    @Column(name = "student_name", insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private String studentName;
    @Column(name = "course_name", insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private String courseName;
    @Column(name = "price", insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private int price;
    @Column(name = "subscription_date", insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private Date subDate;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @Column(name = "registration_date")
    private Date regDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Subscription> subscriptions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Purchaselist> pyrchaselist;
}
```

```
    @NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class Key implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private int studentId;

    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int courseId;
}
```

```
    @NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class PKey implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "student_name")
        private String studentName;

        @Column(name = "course_name")
        private String courseName;
}
```

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "teachers")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```

Comment: Hello, you problem with:
***Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'skillbox.linkedpurchaselist' doesn't exist***
Share please ResultSetReturnImpl class

Comment: Hello, can you explain in more details.
What should i do and how? What is  ResultSetReturnImpl class?